# Repair Leaky Shutoff Valve

Tags: plumbing, valve

The main water shut-off valve coming into my home leaks when it is closed (water turned off to the house).  Is there a way to repair this kind of valve without replacing it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not your normal gate valve so you might be in luck. Shut the water off at your meter. Clean off the valve and try to unscrew the larger of the two nuts to disassemble the valve. Support the body of the valve so you don't crack the solder joint. There should/could be a washer on the valve stem that you can replace. The smaller nut might have to be loosened and some packing/washer replaced too. 
If this doesn't work, then a valve replacement will be necessary. Replace it with a ball valve. Good luck.